# What could have caused this SMD capacitor failure?

Tags: capacitor, pcb, surface-mount, pcb-fabrication, pcb-assembly

I have an 0805 capacitor that has failed short circuit on a board. The maximum voltage it would see should be 16V. It has value 4.7uF, is rated to 25V and is X7R.

I don't understand why it might have failed.

Has anyone seen something like this before and would like to pass on their experience?

It could be physical damage, but then perhaps the damage seen below is from the current when short circuited.

[image: Cap1]

[image: Cap2]

[image: Cap3]

[image: Cap4]

Comment: Looking at the cracks on it, I'd say "a physical impact": Something hit it, or the PCB fell down. Also, since the pick&place is done on a panelized PCB, sometimes components may get cracked during panel break-ups *(I know, my English is terrible. Hope you could understand)*.

Comment: @RohatKılıç your English is fine.

Comment: I've seen similar things caused by physical damage, also when the cap was close to the board edge. Bumping into the edge of a cabinet, a screw/nut or something when the PCB is mounted in place.

Comment: Thanks for your comments

Answer (score 3):

It could have been physically damaged- either big cracks or it could have had micro-cracks. It could simply be a random failure from a latent manufacturing defect.

From murata.com:

[image]

MLCC capacitors are available with "soft" electrodes for higher resistance to cracking. Image from tdk.com

[image]